# 404 not found fetching static files from nodejs/connect.static('../angularjs')

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've seen another question here on SO, but I can't for the life of my figure out why I can't get this to work.  In the same directory as my node installation I ran the commands `npm install` and `npm install connect`.  Then again in the same directory as my node installation I created a server.js file:

```
var connect = require("connect");
var app = connect.createServer().use(connect.static('../angularjs'));
app.listen(8180);
```

so when then I'm again in my root node directory I do `node server.js`
to start the server and it starts fine.  In the root directory of node I made a folder called angularjs and in that folder I placed an index.html.  Whenever I navigate in my browser to localhost:8180/index.html I get the message `Cannot GET /index.html`.  It seems that this should be working, what in the world am I missing here?

Comment: It sounds like `..` is wrong.

Comment: @SLaks i would tend to agree, but I feel like I've tried every permutation and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful about where the directory is. From reading your post it appears that you have a node source directory that contains the angularjs directory, so that's what I created when testing.

On Linux, you can examine the directory and what files are in it with the `ls` or `ls -l` (verbose) commands

Works here with `connect.static()` parameter `./angularjs` and does not work with
 `../angularjs`

Test procedure

```
$ mkdir nodetest
$ cd nodetest
$ mkdir angularjs
$ cat >server.js <<EOF
var connect = require("connect");
var app = connect.createServer().use(connect.static('../angularjs'));
app.listen(8180);
EOF
$ npm install connect
$ emacs ./angularjs/test.html # make a html file to get
$ nodejs ./server.js &
$ wget http://localhost:8180/test.html
# fails 404
$ kill %1 // kill nodejs
$ emacs ./server.js # change ../angularjs to ./angularjs
$ nodejs ./server.js &
$ wget http://localhost:8180/test.html
# works
```

Comment: blah! thanks, i have never seen this one period notation stuff before.  always seen two.  thanks!

Comment: Good luck.  One period and a slash is a subdirectory, two periods and a slash means back up a directory first, like cd .., and then go to that directory.